# Firefox and Chrome do not support cross-domain AJAX by default?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

The following code works as expected in IE8 and Safari4, but not in Firefox3.6 and Chrome. All browsers are on Windows.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() { $('#tabs').tabs(); });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.msn.com/">MSN</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Seems that Firefox and Chrome do not support cross-domain AJAX by default, right? Is there any easy way to turn on cross-domain AJAX in Firefox and Chrome?

Comment: Retagged and removed ajax as this is a problem with the the jQuery UI and not the concept of ajax itself. Also, check out http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#Ajax_mode. Since you are depending on AJAX to load the content then the UI plugin needs to know how to do cross-domain XHR (which I doubt it does).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JSONP (basically, you insert a `<script src="otherdomain.tld/....?callback=your_function"/>` (jQuery does it automagically).

Answer (score 0):

XSS (cross site scripting) is a big bad. Unless you're talking about making security modification to the other to make them support it, I can't believe they would by default.

**Edit**

I just noticed that the code you have there isn't doing any XSS though. What kind of errors (if any) are you getting from this?

Comment: No error shows in the console. But in Firefox and Chrome, nothing shows below the tabs.

Comment: What you're wanting to do should not be default in **any** browser, as it as it is, in fact, CSS and therefore a HUGE security risk to be enabled on a browser.

Answer (score 0):

can this help http://www.ajax-cross-domain.com/ ?

Comment: I'll look at this. But seems that it is not an easy way.